# Is the Turán graph $T_{k,n}$ vertex-transitive when $n$ is a multiple of $k$?

Tags: graph-theory

Take $k,n$ to be two positive integers, such that $n$ is a multiple of $k$, say $n= k m$ for some integer $m$. Consider the [Turán graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph) $T_{k,n}$, i.e. the complete $k$-partite graph with $n$ vertices whose $k$ components have all equal size (namely $n/k=m$).

In many textbook I found a result saying that for $k=2$, the graph described above is vertex-transitive. Is the result still true for $k>2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the result is still true for $k>2$. You could define the required automorphisms directly without too much trouble, but maybe an easier way is to look at the complement of $T_{k,km}$, which is nothing but a disjoint union of $k$ copies of $K_m$. Since such a graph is clearly vertex-transitive, so is $T_{k,km}$.